# How important is Solidity Assembly, as far as market-based on demand dApps are concerned?

Tags: solidity

I am a beginner trying to learn Solidity, enough to be able to make useful dApps. So, is learning Solidity Assembly beneficial to me, as of now?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely. At the moment most smart contract needs can be addressed in Solidity. Assembler is mostly needed for optimization purposes and. Those needs are very minimal in the case of normal dApp development, so learning Solidity assembly would add only very little value for your skill portfolio.